# How can i encrypt my already created columns in sql sever 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, passwords, password-protection, encryption-symmetric

I have simply created my table

```
create table LoginInfo 
(
UserName Varchar(100)constraint user_primary Primary key,
Password Varchar(100),  
Rolleame Varchar(100),  
EmailID Varchar(100)constraint email_unique Unique,
SecurityQuestion Varchar(1000),
SecurityAnswer Varchar(100),
LastLogin datetime
)
```

i want to encrypt it by rsa algorithm. Please tell me how can i encrypt UserName, Password, and security answer.

Comment: At what level you want to encrypt the values at DB level or you want to handle encryption/decryption in your code ?